# Docker Nginx complains: SSL: error:02001002

Tags: ssl, nginx, docker-compose, lets-encrypt

I'm using the following `nginx.conf`

```
worker_processes  1;


events {
worker_connections  1024;
}

http {
include       mime.types;

default_type  application/octet-stream;

sendfile        on;

keepalive_timeout  65;

gzip on;
gzip_disable "msie6";  
gzip_vary on;
gzip_proxied any;
gzip_comp_level 6;
gzip_buffers 16 8k;
gzip_http_version 1.1;
gzip_types text/plain text/css application/json application/x-javascript text/xml application/xml application/xml+rss text/javascript;

server {
  listen         80;
  server_name    mydomain.org;
  return         301 https://$server_name$request_uri;
}


server {

  listen 443 ssl http2;
  ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/mydomain.org/fullchain.pem; 
  ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/mydomain.org/privkey.pem;
  ssl_session_timeout 1d;
  ssl_session_cache shared:SSL:50m;
  ssl_session_tickets off;

  ssl_protocols TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2;
  ssl_ciphers 'ECDHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:ECDHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:DHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:DHE-DSS-AES128-GCM-SHA256:kEDH+AESGCM:ECDHE-RSA-AES128-SHA256:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES128-SHA256:ECDHE-RSA-AES128-SHA:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES128-SHA:ECDHE-RSA-AES256-SHA384:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES256-SHA384:ECDHE-RSA-AES256-SHA:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES256-SHA:DHE-RSA-AES128-SHA256:DHE-RSA-AES128-SHA:DHE-DSS-AES128-SHA256:DHE-RSA-AES256-SHA256:DHE-DSS-AES256-SHA:DHE-RSA-AES256-SHA:!aNULL:!eNULL:!EXPORT:!DES:!RC4:!3DES:!MD5:!PSK';
  ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;
  ssl_dhparam /etc/nginx/certs/dhparam.pem; 

  add_header Strict-Transport-Security max-age=15768000;

  ssl_stapling on;
  ssl_stapling_verify on;


  ssl_trusted_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/mydomain.org/chain.pem; 

  resolver 8.8.8.8 8.8.4.4 valid=86400;

  root /var/www/html;
  index index.php;
  location / {
    try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$args;
  }

  rewrite /wp-admin$ $scheme://$host$uri/ permanent;

  location ~* ^.+\.(ogg|ogv|svg|svgz|eot|otf|woff|mp4|ttf|rss|atom|jpg|jpeg|gif|png|ico|zip|tgz|gz|rar|bz2|doc|xls|exe|ppt|tar|mid|midi|wav|bmp|rtf)$ {
    access_log off; log_not_found off; expires max;
  }

  location ~ [^/]\.php(/|$) {
    fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+?\.php)(/.*)$;
    if (!-f $document_root$fastcgi_script_name) {
        return 404;
    }
      root           /var/www/html;
      fastcgi_pass   wp_db:9000;
      fastcgi_index  index.php;
      fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME /var/www/html$fastcgi_script_name;
      include        fastcgi_params;
  }    
}
}
```

But `nginx` container complains with:

```
nginx: [emerg] BIO_new_file("/etc/letsencrypt/live/mydomain.org/fullchain.pem") failed (SSL: error:02001002:system library:fopen:No such file or directory:fopen('/etc/letsencrypt/live/mydomain.org/fullchain.pem','r') error:2006D080:BIO routines:BIO_new_file:no such file)
```

I have all the certificates on that path for let's encrypt. 
I found this thread 
https://serverfault.com/questions/537343/nginx-startup-fails-ssl-no-such-file-or-directory

And did

```
chown -R root:root /etc/letsencrypt/live/mydomain.org/fullchain.pem
chmod -R 600 /etc/letsencrypt/live/mydomain.org/fullchain.pem
```

Same error was thrown from `nginx` container. I've placed the certs on    `/docker-compose/etc/nginx/certs` giving the same permissions and changing links on `nging.conf` but nothing changed.

What I'm missing?

Comment: I have the same problem. Are you using the Docker for Windows beta?

Comment: I'm using Docker on Debian 8. I'm using now [https-portal](https://github.com/SteveLTN/https-portal) and [letsencrypt-nginx-proxy-companion](https://github.com/JrCs/docker-letsencrypt-nginx-proxy-companion) both working without issues.

Answer (score 8):

I was experiencing the same problem deploying harbor (a docker registry + access control UI) using volume mapping /etc/letsencrypt:/etc/letsencrypt

nginx reported "no such file" when loading the certificate file, even though I could enter that container (docker exec bash ..) and cat the files using the exact same path.

I suspected the problem is caused by letsencrypt use of symlinks, so my solution was to copy the live certs into another folder using cp -rL  (to de-reference symlinks)

```
root@registry:/etc/letsencrypt# mkdir copy
root@registry:/etc/letsencrypt# cp -rL live/* copy/
```

then I changed the nginx.conf to refer to 'copy' instead of 'live'

Now nginx correctly starts inside docker.

This is not a long-term solution because when the certs are renewed the copy won't get automatically updated. But since I'll be running letsencrypt renew  from a cronjob, that task can run the copy process again.

Also I've read that nginx must be restarted if the certs change, so that's another issue I'll need to face. But at least nginx starts correctly now.

Comment: Thanks for this. I'm still having this problem in March 2017. Strange that this hasn't been addressed by Letsencrypt/Docker.

Answer (score 0):

I got this error when I renamed apps in Dokku (0.5.4). What had happened is that the links in the new app directory pointed to the old app name, e.g.

```
/home/dokku/[new app]/letsencrypt/certs/current -> /home/dokku/[old app]/letsencrypt/certs/f1f1f1f1f1f1f1f1f1f1f1f1f1f1f1f1f1f1f1f1
```

So I manually recreated the links so the pointed to the right place.

Answer (score 0):

try to start with `/root` :

```
ssl_certificate         /root/etc/letsencrypt/live/mydomain.org/fullchain.pem;
ssl_certificate_key     /root/etc/letsencrypt/live/mydomain.org/privkey.pem;
```

I solved the problem like this.

Joy

Answer (score -1):

I wasted a day today and found the solution.

Run `nginx` docker engine with

`-v /etc/letsencrypt/archive/your_domain.com:/nginx/letsencrypt/your_domain.com`

and `nginx.conf`

`ssl_certificate         /nginx/letsencrypt/your_domain.com/fullchain1.pem;
ssl_certificate_key     /nginx/letsencrypt/your_domain.com/privkey1.pem;`

Comment: Not sure why this has been downvoted? The symlinks in live point to the archive

Comment: @RonniSkansing I think downvoted is right ! Because in the next renewing, the new certs will be fullchain2, prikey2,... That name make the config is wrong. My idea is bad ! :(